# sql server 2008 database attached error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried to add **luxury database** to my SQL Serever 2008 but I'm getting an error.

It displays below error :

> attach database failed for server 'SAMEER-PC'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
>   An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   Database luxury Drive cannot be upgraded because it is read-only or has read only files. Make the database or files writeable,and rerun recovery.
>   Could not open new database'luxury drive'. CREATE DATABASE id aborted.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3415)

Comment: @Sameer please always **`Google`** before Asking a Question.

Comment: Database luxury Drive cannot be upgraded because it is read-only or has read only files. Make the database or files writeable,and rerun recovery.... please read the error message well

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps :**

- Right click on your `.MDF` , click on properties
  Uncheck `Read Only` property.
- Right click on the folder that contain your `.MDF` , click on properties
  Uncheck `Read Only` property.
- Open **SSMS** ( **S**QL **S**erver **M**anagement **S**tudio).
- Right click on the **DB** in the Object Explorer , Set `Read Only` Property to`FALSE` in the options menu.

Answer (score 0):

File not "only readable" for normaly users but "only readable" for SQL users.

1- Left click your file and select "Properties".

2- Click the "Security" tab.

3- Click "Edit" button.

4- Click "Add..." button.

5- Click "Advanced..."

6- Click "Find Now"

7- Select "OWNER RIGHTS" and click "OK" button.

8- Click "OK" and give "Full Control" and Click "Apply"

8- Repeat until option 4. or Click "Add..." button.

9- write "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER" text area and click "Check Names"

10- Click OK button.

Last; give "Full control" the users.

Do this to .mdf and .ldf files.

Have nice day. ;)

Answer (score -1):

The user not have the permissions to access.

**[The below link was helpful in figuring out the problem.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1367859.aspx)**

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929043/error-attaching-a-database-mdf-file-to-sql-server)**